# C# get ATTLIST element-name

Tags: c#, xml, dtd

According to W3Schools an [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_attributes.asp) of an XML has the following sintax:

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type attribute-value>
```

So on C# I can read all the elements of any XML with the following [code](http://diranieh.com/NETXML/XmlReader):

```
    XmlReaderSettings readSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    readSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    readSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"d:\temp\xml-sign.xml", readSettings))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.Write(reader.NodeType.ToString().PadRight(20, '-'));
            Console.Write("> ".PadRight(reader.Depth * 5));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name = {0}, Value = {1}", reader.Name, reader.Value));
        }
    }
```

As an example of xml file and output:

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- This is a comment -->

<!DOCTYPE Test [<!ATTLIST Book Id ID #IMPLIED>]>         
    <Book Id="ABC">
        <Author>Yazan Diranieh</Author>
        <ISBN>12345</ISBN>
        <Publisher>Publisher 1</Publisher>
    </Book>
```

**Output**

```
XmlDeclaration------> Name = xml, Value = version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"
Comment-------------> Name = , Value =  This is a comment
DocumentType--------> Name = Test, Value = <!ATTLIST Book Id ID #IMPLIED>
Element-------------> Name = Book, Value =
Element------------->    Name = Author, Value =
Text---------------->         Name = , Value = Yazan Diranieh
EndElement---------->    Name = Author, Value =
Element------------->    Name = ISBN, Value =
Text---------------->         Name = , Value = 12345
EndElement---------->    Name = ISBN, Value =
Element------------->    Name = Publisher, Value =
Text---------------->         Name = , Value = Publisher 1
EndElement---------->    Name = Publisher, Value =
EndElement----------> Name = Book, Value =
```

In the following line I have the information I need, the attribute:
**`DocumentType--------> Name = Test, Value = <!ATTLIST Book Id ID #IMPLIED>`**

I need to get the element-name of the attribute, in this case, "**Book**"

There´s same method to do this? Or should I use some search string in this value?

Comment: It says a DTD is declared with a ATTLIST thing on your link. You should re-read that before you continue.

Comment: @ChuckSavage sorry man, I didn´t got wat you mean with, "You should re-read..". Should I re-read the article on link, because I missed something, ou should I change my code to re-read the DocumentType´s node to get the information?

Comment: *"According to W3Schools an attribute of an XML has the following sintax"*. What it says is that an **attribute declaration in a DTD** has that syntax. That is not the same as an actual attribute in an XML file. What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Why do you need the element name?

Comment: I need the name because it´s a dynamic field on my project. It contains the tag name that I should to sign on XML. So I need the name to pass as a parameter to a function that sign the XML with a x509 certificate.